# Cannot makemigrations with Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm using Django to try and make a portfolio website. I've added two apps called 'Jobs' and 'Blogs' using `python manage.py startapp 'appname'`.

I then went into Atom and to the models.py file to implement `class Job(models.Model):`

We then had to go into settings.py to add `'jobs.apps.JobsConfig'` to the INSTALLED_APPS.

After that I added `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'` and `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` and then went back to the command prompt to `python manage.py makemigrations` which keeps leading to this error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()}
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line   115, in inner_run
  autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\NAME\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
  raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\NAME\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute
  autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\NAME\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
  app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in create
  mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jobs'
```

I have installed Pillow via Pip and I've tried several versions of Pillow all the way back down to 8.1.0.

I'm quite new to programming and I'm pretty much stumped after looking around through google and stack overflow.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You likely have `'jobs'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` but there is no Django app named `jobs`.

Comment: Hey Will, I have a folder in Atom called jobs which appeared when I did startapp:

https://i.gyazo.com/e2c0688108b10a1fbe18cf5a1864b875.png

Is that not the Django app?

Comment: that's `Jobs` with an *uppercase* (normally modules have no uppercase), but then it thus should be `'Jobs'`.

Comment: LOL now I feel dumb, thanks Will

Comment: hehehe, its very okat @FruityJohn, even experienced developers mix letters

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions hope it will work
Lets say you want to make a project named **mysite** and create a app named **polls**
First create the apps inside the project directory

Then you can create the first view. Open the file polls/views.py and put the following Python code in it:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
    
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Create a file called **urls.py** then inside that **polls** directory and include the following code.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Then inside the **mysite/urls.py** file add point the root URLconf

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Add the app inside the mysite/settings it will look like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',]
```

For more details check the link : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/